# SU Retag Request: [*filter(ing)] --> [filter(ing)]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

- [filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filter)
- [filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filtering)
- [web-filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-filtering)
- [spam-filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spam-filtering)
- [traffic-fitering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/traffic-fitering)

The above listed questions may benefit from splitting the tags apart
and housing them under [filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filter) or [filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filtering). What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filtering) into [filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filter) however I am not certain about the others. I think seperating them because of different focusses may be acceptable in this case.

I have merged the tags and created the synonym.